# How to get the ManyToMany Manager object using the field name

Tags: django, django-orm, django-managers

I have a Django model with multiple ManyToMany fields. I want to query one of them dynamically, according to the field name, inside a method of this model.

How do I get the ManyToMany manager object using only the field name.
Is it possible?

Comment: do you know the field name of m2m relationship? or it is coming as parameter in method and accordingly field will be determined?

Comment: coming as string parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get attribute value dynamically. Use `getattr`

```
def method(self, param_name):
    field = getattr(self, param_name)
    all = field.all()
```

This should help.